Verifying proof that in a first countable space if $u_n\to u$ and $f(u_n)\to f(u)$, then $f$ is continuous
Let $S$ and $T$ be topological spaces with $S$ first countable and $\varphi: S \to T$. Then $\varphi$ is continuous iff for every sequence $\{u_n\}$ converging to $u$, $\{\varphi(u_n)\}$ converges to $\varphi(u)$, for all $u \in S$.
The only if part, my proof:For arbitrary $A$ with $A \subset S$, we have a sequence of points$\{u_n\}$ in $A$ that converges to $u$ for $u \in cl(A)$,so $\{\varphi(u_n)\}$ converges to $\varphi(u)$,that is, for any point $u \in \varphi(cl(A))$,$ u \in cl(\varphi(A))$,so $\varphi(cl(A)) \subset cl(\varphi(A))$,so $\varphi$ is continuous.
Q.E.D
My intuition told me that my proof has something wrong in it, because I haven't use the condition of first countability ,but I don't know where the proof goes invalid.Could someone please help me?

The fact that $u \in \text{cl}(A)$ implies that there is a sequence $\{u_n\}$ of points in $A$ that converges to $u$ is true because the space is first countable.
This is not true for any topological space.
